# Prevent Listbox from display partial Listboxitem

Tags: c#, wpf, listbox

I have a non-interactive UI that displays information. The information is held in a Listbox control with a custom listboxitem control.

The size of each listboxitem can vary, the window can be resized as required by the user.

I want to prevent listboxitems which are partially shown in the application from showing, this will always be the last row. However, if I resize the UI, the 'last row' will change.

I've been experimenting with [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6045299/prevent-wpf-listview-or-listbox-from-showing-half-items) without any luck.

```
protected override Size ArrangeOverride(Size finalSize)
        {
        // Arrange in a stack
            double curX = 0;
            double curY = 0;
            foreach (UIElement child in InternalChildren)
            {
                double nextY = curY + child.DesiredSize.Height;
                if (nextY > finalSize.Height)         // Don't display partial items
                    child.Arrange(new Rect());
                else
                    child.Arrange(new Rect(curX, curY, child.DesiredSize.Width, child.DesiredSize.Height));
                curY = nextY;
            }

            return finalSize;

        }
```

"InternalChildren" I assume is my listbox, but Listbox is not enumerable. I'm not sure how to use this example.

How can I achieve the desired result?

**Main Control**

```
<UserControl x:Class="Cis.CustomControls.CisDeparturesPanel"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
             xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
             xmlns:customControls="clr-namespace:Cis.CustomControls"
             mc:Ignorable="d" d:DesignHeight="600" d:DesignWidth="800">
    <UserControl.Resources>
        <DataTemplate x:Key="DataTemplate">

            <ListBoxItem Padding="0"  >
                <customControls:CisDeparturesRow />
            </ListBoxItem>

        </DataTemplate>
    </UserControl.Resources>

    <Grid>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="48"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="44"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="229*"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="279*" />
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>


        <ListBox Grid.Row="2" HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch" Name="ListBoxDepart" Background="Black" Margin="1,0,-1,0" BorderThickness="0" ItemsSource="{Binding Path=StationMovementList}" ItemTemplate="{StaticResource DataTemplate}" ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Hidden" ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Hidden" Grid.RowSpan="2">
            <ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
                <Style TargetType="{x:Type ListBoxItem}">
                    <Setter Property="Focusable" Value="False"/>
                </Style>
            </ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>

        </ListBox>


    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

**ListBoxItem Custom Control**

```
<UserControl x:Class="Cis.CustomControls.CisDeparturesRow"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
             xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
             mc:Ignorable="d" d:DesignHeight="80" d:DesignWidth="800" Background="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor,AncestorType={x:Type UserControl}}, Path=Background}" HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch" Margin="0,0,0,0" Width="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor,AncestorType={x:Type UserControl}}, Path=ActualWidth}">
    <UserControl.Resources>
<!-- snip --->
</UserControl.Resources>
    <Grid x:Name="ArrivalRowGrid">
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="47*"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="33*"/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="141"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="117"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="241"/>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

        <TextBlock Name="TxtDestinationName" MouseDown="TxtDestinationName_OnMouseDown" Style="{StaticResource MainRowStyle}"  TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="{Binding Path=DestinationName,NotifyOnTargetUpdated=True, Mode=OneWay}" Margin="10,0"/>
        <TextBlock Name="TxtPlatNum" TextWrapping="Wrap" Style="{StaticResource MainRowStyle}" Text="{Binding Path=Platform,NotifyOnTargetUpdated=True, Mode=OneWay}" Margin="11,0,8,0"
                   Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1"/>

        <TextBlock Name="TxtArrTime" TextWrapping="Wrap" Style="{StaticResource MainRowStyle}" TextAlignment="Right" Text="{Binding Path=ExpectedDepartureTime,NotifyOnTargetUpdated=True, Mode=OneWay}" Margin="10,0,21,8"
                   Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="3" />

        <TextBlock Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0" Grid.ColumnSpan="4" x:Name="TxtCallingAt" TextWrapping="Wrap" Style="{StaticResource SubRowStyle}" TextAlignment="Left" Text="{Binding Path=CallingAt,NotifyOnTargetUpdated=True, Mode=OneWay}" Margin="10,0,21,0" />

    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The SO question that you link to contains an `ArrangeOverride` method that is for use on a custom `Panel`, not the `ListBox` itself.

A WPF `ListBox` control's template, once it has been expanded, looks kind of like this (simplified of course):

```
<Border>
    <ScrollViewer>
        <SomePanel>
            <ListBoxItem>your item</ListBoxItem>
            <ListBoxItem>your item</ListBoxItem>
            <ListBoxItem>your item</ListBoxItem>
            <ListBoxItem>etc</ListBoxItem>
        </SomePanel>
    </ScrollViewer>
</Border>
```

where `SomePanel` is an instance of a class that derives from `Panel`. The default for a list box is a `VirtualizingStackPanel` but that can be replaced like so:

```
<ListBox>
    <ListBox.ItemsPanel>
        <ItemsPanelTemplate>
            your panel type here
        </ItemsPanelTemplate>
    </ListBox.ItemsPanel>
</ListBox>
```

You said in your question this was for a "non-interactive UI". That has several different interpretations, but implies to me that you could replace the `ListBox` with an `ItemsControl` because you don't need the selection abilities of the list box. Then create a custom panel (a class that derives from `Panel`), add the `ArrangeOverride` method from the linked SO question, and replace the `ItemControl`'s panel with your custom one.

Comment: Thank you, I've created my custom panel with the MessureOverride and ArrangeOverride and added it into my data template, however I can still see the last partial item.  ( added surrounding <customControls:CisDeparturesRow /> ) Can you advise why the partial item still shows?

Comment: Not sure. Could be because the default `ListBox` control template includes the `ScrollViewer` which will basically give the child panel infinite height to play with, hence as far as the `ArrangeOverride` method is concerned there is always enough height to display all of the items. Do you need to be able to scroll the list? If not, there is a different approach you could take.

Comment: I've rethought the approach and I'm catching the Onloaded event of the ItemsControl and iterating through each row and calculating the size of each row and hiding rows that are larger than the parent container. Seems to work. Your explanation helped me find the right path. Thank you.